# Wicket - <wicket:link> - How to put pages in different packages?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a web app, and it has a directory structure like:

```
/com/myproject/MyPage.java
/com/myproject/MyPage.html
/com/myproject/resources/styles.css
/com/myproject/resources/bg.png
```

In `MyPage.html` I have code like:

```
<wicket:link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/styles.css"/>
</wicket:link>
```

The CSS file has references like `url(bg.png)`. And all is good.

However, my app is now getting so big (I have about 15 pages so far), I don't want to put all the pages and HTML in one directory. However things like "styles.css" are referenced from all pages. So I would like to create various packages for various groups of pages, but still have "styles.css", and the images etc. that it references, existing only once in my source tree.

I would like to do something like:

- Create e.g. `/com/myproject/usermanagement/UserManagementStartPage.java`
- but still have `/com/myproject/resources/styles.css` (with the intention of sharing that between all pages)
- The HTML still references the CSS with a `<wicket:link>`, e.g. `href="../resources/styles.css"`
- Or even better, have an absolute link to the css e.g. `href="/com/myproject/resources/styles.css` (that way when I move a page from one package to a deeper/shallower package, I don't have to change the number of `..`.)

Am I thinking along the right lines? How would you approach this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like:

```
<wicket:link>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="$up$/resources/styles.css"/>
</wicket:link>
```

org.apache.wicket.settings.IResourceSettings.setParentFolderPlaceholder("$up$")

This way the url will look like /com/myproject/usermanagement/$up$/resources/styles.css and Wicket will resolve the parent folder for you.

Comment: OK that sounds great! I suppose that means, the advantage, that one can open a Wicket HTML file in a browser directly (e.g. when the web designer is working), and have it look reasonable, is lost then? I suppose one could have a `<wicket:remove>` around a link to "../resources/styles.css" and then secondly the `<wicket:link>` as you've suggested.

Answer (score 2):

Wicket handles CSS file links that are relative to the root of the web app. That way, it doesn't matter if you move a markup file one level higher or deeper. It is also possible to include style sheets from Java code, as explained 
[in this article](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363828/Introducing-Apache-Wicket) . Using markup inheritance, you can just add your style sheet to your base page and let your real pages inherit from it.

Comment: "Wicket handles CSS file links that are relative to the root of the web app", Cool, what is the syntax for this? Just `href="/com/myproject/resources/styles.css"`? Or would I put the static files into the WAR directly (not in `WEB-INF/classes` or in a JAR), and use that syntax?

Comment: The root of your web app is the directory where the WEB-INF folder is located, usually called 'web' or 'webapp'. Putting the styles.css in the Java package structure when it's not directly related to a Wicket component does not sound like a good idea to me.